# stop sidebar at the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery

I have a sidebar on a page which scrolls up and down whenever a user scrolls. Everything works fine apart from at the end of the page. I want the bar to stop scrolling once it is at the bottom of the page. I've tried putting in a `while` loop but that crashes my page and makes it unresponsive each time I scroll. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

The code I have so far is:

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );
  $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
      var nTop = $(window).scrollTop() + parseInt(el.attr('data-top'));
      var nBottom = nTop + $(window).height();
      console.log("Top => " + nTop);
      console.log("Bottom => "+ nBottom);
      while(nBottom < $(document).height()) {
          el.animate({
              top: nTop
          }, 500);
          if (nBottom == $(document).height()) {
              break;
          }
      }
  }, 250) );
});
```

CSS

```
#social-bar {
position: fixed;
top: 120px;
left: -50px;
width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: instead of making the sidebar scroll, why not use CSS to give it "position:fixed". As long as you arrange everything else correctly, it'll just stay in place as the user scrolls through the rest of the page. Much simpler.

Comment: @ADyson It's one of the requirements to make the bar scroll as soon as the user starts to scroll the page

Comment: if you use position fixed then it'll look like it's scrolling, but you won't have to write any JS. If the sidebar is too large for the height of the page, then set `overflow:scroll` on it as well and then the user can scroll within the sidebar separately. I assume the objective here is to ensure the sidebar stays visible at all times?

Comment: @ADyson Yes I need to make sure the side bar is visible at all times.

Comment: @ADyson I've tried your suggestion but the sidebar still carries on scroll when at the bottom of the page

Comment: have you removed your js code?

Comment: @ADyson I just removed the js code and the bar now stays in one place. I'll update my OP to include the css I have for the div

Comment: does it stay in the same place even when the user scrolls through the rest of the page?

Comment: @ADyson The sidebar stays at the top of the page even if the user is scrolling through the page

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super-simple example of what I've been talking about in the comments. This involves using css positioning to ensure that the sidebar stays visible at all times. No javascript is required. If you add sufficient text within `<div id=content>` to make the page need to scroll, you can see that the sidebar remains visible all the time, avoiding the need for complicated javascript to try and make it move down the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#sidebar
{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:10%;
}
#content
{
  margin-left:10%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li class='menu-item active'><a href='index.html' >Home</a></li>
    <li class='menu-item'><a href='page1.html' >Page 1</a></li>
    <li class='menu-item'><a href='page2.html' >Page 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  Put enough content here to require scrolling. You can auto-generate random text at http://www.lipsum.com
</div>
</body>
</html>
```